# docker postgres init script seems will not create db user, command is ignored

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD password
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB evesde


COPY init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and my init file is chmod' to 777:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U "postgres" -d "evesde" -e "create role yaml with login encrypted password 'password';"
```

when running a container it will say:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "create role yaml with
> login encrypted password 'password';" ignored

Im not sure why this is happening, and when doing an interactive terminal, this command seemingly worked.  I dont see any additional information and wasnt sure what was going wrong.

The postgres docker page is: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

When looking at it deeper, I was noticing that running the command itself fails in an interactive Terminal with the same error, but the command runs when I am in postgres:  `psql -U "postgres" -d "evesde"` and run the command, it works.

I think it may be related to passing the command in through the exec command is where it fails.  likely related to `'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `-c` instead of `-e`.

`-e` turns on "echo queries"

`-c` runs the command and exits

Have you considered putting just the `create role` command in a file called `create_role.sql` and copying that into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`?

Based on testing, it looks like an equivalent but simpler solution is to put the SQL command as one line in a file, `00_roles.sql`, and copy that into the container instead of the `init.sh` script.

Comment: I was thinking that as an option based on what the entrypoint does, but i was trying to have 1 init script which processes it.  I think i will give this an attempt as well.  Do you have a sample file?  I didnt think it would be as easy as just having that in an .sql file. I figured there might be other metadata?

I was worried about the order of operations, since after it will do a pg_restore, BUT it seems that it will do SQL/DB files, then Executable SH files, then Source Non executable SH files.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I just tried it by putting `create role yaml with login encrypted password 'password';` on a single line inside of a file called `00_roles.sql` and copied that instead of the init.sh.  I connected to shell, `su postgres`, and `\du+` showed the `yaml` role.  The "00" on the filename will help you deal with order of operations within the predefined ordering of types of files.

Comment: yeah, This works and I think is the best approach!! :) Thank you.